# data.table not returning the correct splinefun by group

Tags: r, data.table, spline

We have recently updated our `data.table` from version `1.12.0` to `1.12.8` and R from `3.5.3` to `3.6.3`. The example is on Windows OS.

We have a `data.table` where we are looping over a Category column and creating a `splinefun` object to use later on. We store this `splinefun` function outputs in to a `list`, within a `data.table` column. It worked as expected on our old specs, producing a `splinefun` unique for each category level based on the segmented data. However, now it looks like its just keeping the value for the final category and parsing it in to all the entries.

**Setup Data**

create some fake data for showing the issue

```
# R version: 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
library(data.table) # data.table_1.12.8
library(ggplot2)
library(stats) 

# mimic our data in simpler format
set.seed(1)
dt <- data.table(cat = rep(letters[1:3], each = 10),
                 x = 1:10)
dt[, y := x^0.5 * rnorm(.N, mean=runif(1, 1, 100), sd=runif(1, 1, 10)), by=cat]

# can see that each line is different
pl0 <- ggplot(data=dt, aes(x=x, y=y, col=cat)) + geom_line()
pl0
```

**Fit Splines**

Fit the splines via our current method and using `lapply` for comparison. `lapply` works as expected, `data.table` doesn't.

```
# fit spline, segment the data by category
mod_splines <- dt[, .(Spline = list(splinefun(x=x, y=y, method = "natural"))),
                  by = c("cat")]

# splinefun works such that you provide new values of x and it gives an output
# y from a spline fitted to y~x
# Can see they are all the same, which seems unlikely
mod_splines$Spline[[1]](5)
mod_splines$Spline[[2]](5)
mod_splines$Spline[[3]](5)

# alternative approach
alt_splines <-  lapply(unique(dt$cat), function(x_cat){
  splinefun(x=dt[cat==x_cat, ]$x, 
            y=dt[cat==x_cat, ]$y, 
            method = "natural")
})

# looks more realistic
alt_splines[[1]](5)
alt_splines[[2]](5)
alt_splines[[3]](5) # Matches the mod_splines one!
```

**Checking whether `splinefun` is fitting**

The data and outputs of the `splinefun` look correct when we print out from within the data.table loop, but it doesn't get stored correctly.

```
# check the data is segmenting
mod_splines2 <- dt[, .(Spline = list(splinefun(x=x, y=y, method = "natural")),
                      x=x, y=y),
                  by = c("cat")]
mod_splines2[] # the data is definitely segmenting ok

# try catching and printing the data
splinefun_withmorefun <- function(x, y){

  writeLines(paste(x, collapse =", "))
  writeLines(paste(round(y, 0), collapse =", "))

  foo <- splinefun(x=x, 
            y=y, 
            method = "natural")
  writeLines(paste(foo(5), collapse =", "))
  writeLines("")
  return(foo)
}

# looks like its in the function ok, as it prints out different results 
mod_splines3 <- dt[, .(Spline = list(splinefun_withmorefun(x=x, y=y))),
                   by = c("cat")]

# but not coming through in to the listed function
mod_splines3$Spline[[1]](5)
mod_splines3$Spline[[2]](5)
mod_splines3$Spline[[3]](5)
```

Any ideas why this would be an issue after updates would be great! We're worried there may be other cases using a similar `data.table` methodology that could now be silently broken as this one was.

Thank you,
Jonny

Comment: I had issues with a slightly older version of data.table regarding aggregation that was corrected in version 1.12.4. Could it be related to the fixes here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/59886170/698590

Comment: I'm using `1.12.8` so shouldn't have this issue. I think it's different in that its not erroring or providing a warning but rather the outputs aren't returned correctly in to the list, so instead of `list(obj1, obj2, obj3)` its returning `list(obj3, obj3, obj3)`, the final element multiple times, where each `obj` correspond to a level of the grouping calculation

Comment: Oh, I just meant because you were upgrading from 1.12.0 to 1.12.8. I understand the issue isn't quite the same, but I was trying to answer your point `"Any ideas why this would be an issue after updates would be great!"` that there were some under-the-hood adjustments over the last few versions that may be the culprit. Unfortunately, I don't think I can provide much more help than that for you.

Comment: FWIW I see the same incorrect output in 1.12.0

Comment: Ah that's interesting... The programme that uses 1.12.0 is ran on Linux I realise, so maybe it's a difference in the OS. We haven't yet got the latest data.table/R ready for linux and are doing some windows testing first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I've answered in https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/4298#issuecomment-597737776 , adding `copy()` on `x` and `y` variables will solve this issue.

The reason is that `splinefun()` would try to store the values of `x` and `y`. However, the internal object of `data.table` is always passed by reference (for the speed)... On this case, you may have to explicitly `copy()` the variable in order to have expected answers.

In short, changing

```r
mod_splines <- dt[, .(Spline = list(splinefun(x=x, y=y, method = "natural"))),
                  by = c("cat")]
```

to

```r
mod_splines <- dt[, .(Spline = list(splinefun(x=copy(x), y=copy(y), method = "natural"))),
                  by = c("cat")]
```

or this (you can ignore this, but it may give you a better understanding)

```r
mod_splines <- dt[, .(Spline = list(splinefun(x=x+0, y=y+0, method = "natural"))),
                  by = cat]
```

is enough.